# How do I publish a separate appsettings.json file when publishing a single .exe?

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I have a console App with a config file. When I publish using the new *PublishSingleFile* setting in the .proj it publishes the app as one file (good) but it also adds the appsettings to that .exe.

This means it isn't really a config file at this point and more a file hard coded values.

How do I publish with a separate config file?

current .proj settings

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
   <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
   <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
   <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
   <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: You can have appsettings that target specific environments - like Development, Production etc  -is that your question? But this is in the .NetCore environment though.

Comment: I keep the original version in the parent folder, then I take it to the proper folder every publication. On Windows I noticed you could refer the parent folder, but it does not work on Linux.

Comment: @Rakesh no sorry, I mean when I publish using dotnet publish I get the .exe but the appsettings.json is inside the exe not alongside it, so it can't be edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

solved it, needed the following in the .csproj

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="*.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```